# Using Excel "IF" Function to Assign Months to Cells

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a spreadsheet containing multiple cells that are formatted as dates.  What I would like to do is write an "IF" statement that I can copy and paste that will check the first value in the cell and then come up with a month.  For example, I have a cell that has a value of **9/30/2014** and I am trying to do the following:

```
IF(LEFT(A2,1) = 9, "September", "NULL")
```

This is throwing me a value of "NULL" for some reason.  Any guidance on how to get this to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dates are not handled as strings. They are the number of days since 1900-Jan-0. You need to convert the date to its month number.

```
=IF(MONTH(A2)=9,"September","Null")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your source cell A2 is formatted as text, enclose the value 9 within double quotes.

Like this `=IF(LEFT(A2,1) = "9", "September", "NULL")`

Comment: It is formatted as a date, though.  How do I deal with that?

Comment: =IF(MONTH(A2) = 9, "September", "NULL")

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to return the month from a date is:

```
=TEXT(A1,"mmmm")
```

**Example:**

[image]